# Can I reduce the free space on my windows 8 Restore partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-8.1, ssd

I recently did a hard drive clone from the out-of-the-box HDD of my new laptop to a smaller SSD. The cloning software (Acronis True Image HD) handled the resizing of the primary partition to make it fit on the SSD, but none of the other partition sizes were changed.

During this cloning process, I noticed that the Restore partition is only using 10 GB of its allocated 20 GB of space. I'm wondering if reducing the partition size to its needed 10 GB and reallocating the free space to my primary partition?

A few pertinent facts:

- Windows 8.1, OEM license
- No OS media provided (i.e., restores/recoveries are handled from the hard drive, not a DVD)
- My particular model laptop (ASUS Q551L Best Buy exclusive) doesn't offer the option to separately purchase an OEM OS restore DVD, so if I screw up the Restore drive I'd have to buy a full windows 8 copy.

Comment: You do understand Microsoft has a tool that will generate the Windows 8.1 .iso all you need is your license key which you can by using any number of tools including the free software `Speccy`.  You should do this no matter want since you clearly don't have an installation disk.

Comment: I did not, but that's good to know, I'll check it out. Do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: Yes;  You can decrease the partition.  I suggest creating an image of just that partition.  That way you can delete the partition and create a new partition +10% require to restore the partition.  If you don't select to backup the free space that should work for you.  The problem you will run into is you need to then delete your system partition in order to merge it with partition that exists before it on the disk.

Comment: Thanks! Going back to your original suggestion, I did some Googling and it seems like Windows 8.1 OEM only allows you to make a Recovery/System Repair Disk, which doesn't actually replace the Restore partition (ie cannot be used to reinstall windows). https://www.winhelp.us/create-a-recovery-drive-in-windows-8.html

Comment: It also looks like a Windows OEM license key won't work with a Windows 8.1 ISO download from Microsofts website.

Comment: Nevermind, my last comment is incorrect: http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/38486-need-help-formatted-genuine-windows-8-lenovo.html#post330277